# Assign each value from one list to another with different number of indexes

Tags: python

I want to assign each letter from list letters to each number from list numbers, but they have different indexes so when x grows above 4 error appears. How to solve this?

```
letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
x = 0
y = 0
for i in #?:

    print(letters[x] + numbers[y])
    if x < 4:
        x += 1
        y += 1
    elif x == 4:
        y += 1
```

I want my output to be:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
B1
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product
for letter, number in product(letters, numbers):
    print(letter + number)
```

This outputs:

```py
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
D1
D2
D3
D4
D5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using double for loop:

```
for l in letters:
    for n in numbers:
        print(l+n)
```

Or one-liner:

```
print("\n".join(l+n for l in letters for n in numbers))
```

**Output**

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
D1
D2
D3
D4
D5
​
```

Comment: Simple, two-dimensional, effective - particularly the nested for-loops ️.

Answer (score -1):

More or less from what I understood, the code would look like this:

```py
letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(0, len(letters)):
    print(letters[x] + numbers[y])
    if x < 4:
        x += 1
        y += 1
    elif x == 4:
        y += 1
```

The result comes out like this:

```
A1
B2
C3
D4
```

Comment: This is not at all the expected output.